# resize:both behaves different when changing size in JS before first interaction

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe

I use `resize:both;` in CSS to resize my Iframe.
I have one problem when resizing the Iframe programmatically.

If the iframe was resized manually(i.e. manual drag)  and **then** was resized programmatically(using JS), the Iframe is behaving as it should behave and can get resized to any size.

If however the iframe **was not** resized manually(i.e. manual drag) and then was resized programmatically(using JS) to a bigger size, this new size becomes the minimum size the Iframe can have and the Iframe can only get bigger in size.

```
<div>
        <input type="button" value="Maxmize" onclick="ButtonClick()"></input>
        <input type="button" value="Remove"></input>
        <div>
            <iframe id="theId" class="Resizer" src="">
            </iframe>
        </div>
               </div>

           <style type="text/css">
           .Resizer {resize: both;}
           </style>
           <script>
           function ButtonClick() {
                var iFrame = document.getElementById("theId");
                var iFrameStyleAttr = document.createAttribute('style');
                iFrameStyleAttr.nodeValue = 'width:400px;height:300px;';
                iFrame.setAttributeNode(iFrameStyleAttr);
            }
           </script>
```

How can I achieve in whichever case the ability to reduce the size of the Iframe?

**EDIT: I would rather have a solution without the use of JQuery or any similar libraries.**

**EDIT 2: I need a solution to work on Google Chrome 28.0**

Answer (score 1):

I believe that iframes are not resizable by default. Your solution works for me only on Chrome 28.0.

It would be much more easier to use jQuery and jQuery UI.
Try appending those files to the head section of your document:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then you should set the initial width and height for both the iframe and the div which contains it:

```
<style type="text/css">
    div#iFrameCon, .Resizer { width: 150px; height: 50px; }
</style>
```

As you can see, I've given the div and the maximize button id attributes so it's easier to select them with jQuery:

```
<input id="Maximize" type="button" value="Maxmize"></input>
<input type="button" value="Remove"></input>
<div id="iFrameCon">
    <iframe id="theId" class="Resizer ui-widget-content" src="">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Now all you need is the jQuery UI Resizable plugin which enables the iframe and it's container to be resized with simple drag method:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
        $("#iFrameCon").resizable({
            alsoResize: "#theId"
        });
        $("#Maximize").click(function(){
            $("#iFrameCon, #theId").css({ "width": "400px", "height": "300px"});
        });
   });
</script>
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

Ok, so this is the pure JS and CSS approach. I've tested it and it works in FF v.22 and Chrome 28.0. However it fails in all versions of IE.

```
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Maxmize" onclick="ButtonClick()"></input>
    <input type="button" value="Remove"></input>
    <div id="iFrameCon">
        <iframe id="theId" class="Resizer" src="">
        </iframe>
    </div>
 </div>

<style type="text/css">
div#iFrameCon { resize: both; overflow: auto; height: 100px; width: 300px; }
.Resizer { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
</style>
<script>
   function ButtonClick() {
        var iFrameCon = document.getElementById("iFrameCon");
        iFrameCon.style.width = "400px";
        iFrameCon.style.height = "300px";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Id rather have a solution without JQuery. If it can be done with pure CSS than I would rather have that solution. Good Answer though.

Comment: I'm afraid that if you want it to be cross-browser and to work properly it won't be possible with CSS only. Also programming it in pure JS would be a total reinvention of the wheel. However, as it comes to web-developing you cannot be always sure sth is absolutely impossible, therefore maybe somebody else will find some way around ;)

Comment: The edited solution works as expected in FF.In Chrome however, it basically has the same problem as stated in the Question and on top of that there are two cursors that one can resize from, which is making the design look weak. Actually I want a solution that works on Chrome, because that is what is being used in the company I am working for and this is an internal project. Much appretiation for the FF solution..